# List indices must be integer, not tuple

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to separate multiple lists (more lists are created when specified by user input) and when trying to specify how many to make (0 to user input) it says

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

I have looked quite a lot on StackOverflow but cannot find anything that could help with my problem. I have tried changing variables around and have tried setting the user input to an integer multiple times but it still only seems to stay as a tuple. Any help would be appreciated.

My code:

```
def rle():
    askq = int(input("How many lines of RLE compressed data do you want to enter?"))
    if askq < 2:
        print("You must enter at least 2 lines of RLE compressed data.")
        rle()
    print("Please enter your RLE compressed data one line at a time")
    lines = []
    for i in range (0, askq):
        i = input("Which lines would you like to convert?")
        lines.append(i)
    num = int(askq)
    lines2 = []
    for x in range(0, askq):
        x = list(lines[0, num])

    print (x)
```

obviously it's not finished, because I can only complete this function when my problem is solved

I expect the output of x to be

```
[#separated input], [#separated input] etc...
```

however I get the error message:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: I am also trying to map the lists

Comment: provide complete error message

Comment: File "\\srv9\cs5\Documents\WORK\Program.py", line 45, in rle
    x = list(lines[0, num])
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple

Comment: Try `x = list(lines[0:num])`

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do with `lines2` but the problem is `lines[0, num]`, maybe you mean `lines[:num]` ?

Comment: I made an error in my first piece of code. I am also trying to map the lists and so I get a syntax error when I use "[0:num]"

Answer (score 0):

Is your program taking the line inputs correctly?
I ran your code on my machine and it seems it is ignoring the prompt "Please enter your RLE compressed data one line at a time".
The error might be occurring because the variables lines and lines2 are not initiated.

EDIT :

I think you are trying to achieve this. You can modify the lines_input as you suit.

```
def rle():
askq = int(input("How many lines of RLE compressed data do you want to enter?"))
if askq < 2:
    print("You must enter at least 2 lines of RLE compressed data.")
    rle()
print("Please enter your RLE compressed data one line at a time")
lines = []
for i in range (0, askq):
    i = input("Which lines would you like to convert?")
    lines.append(i)
lines_input = [1,2]
lines2 = []
num=0
x = []
for i in range(0,askq):
    num+=1
    if num in lines_input:
        x.append(lines[i])

print (lines)
print(x)
```

Suppose the input is ['ffsf', 'dwdw', 'dwd', 'dwd', 'gfwg']

Then the output will be ['ffsf', 'dwdw'] because lines_input is taking 1st and 2nd line as input.

Comment: lines2[ ] is essentially a list that i'm going to use to store something later in the function, but I don't need it now. What do you mean by initiated the variable?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you are trying to input some data first in the 'lines' variable.

Comment: You can use [0:num] but basically what your program is doing is creating a copy of lines list. So if you print both lines and x you will find out the outputs are same.

Comment: Thank you! It is working almost completely, but it prints twice. Also, how would I be able to separate this character by character? 
Thanks - 
Jake